# Request between client and API. Get or Post? Is the information protected by the certificate?

Tags: ssl, post, https, get, request

**Ignore the following, go to "@edit2"**

*i read a lot about SSL certificates but still i can't figure out the following:
I have a program that does a POST to my API, how do i make this program do it using the Certificate, i mean to protect the information sent.
Do i have to include the certificate in the client? or when it does the post it first asks the server for the certificate?
In the case that it should include the certificate, isn't that unsafe?
Because stackoverflow asks me to say the following:
I already tried reading a lot about SSL certificates, this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/https-explained-with-carrier-pigeons-7029d2193351 helped me a lot but still i don't get how it works for my case.
If there is any way i can try, any website that i can easy use to make an HTTPS Post, please tell me.
Thanks in advance*

*@edit1: To be honest, after posting this i found the right words to search on google and i found this post:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110621/ssl-newbie-does-https-client-also-need-a-certificate
But i wanted to know if this applies for the following case:
file.exe doing POST to api on server (sending username and password), server answering the file.exe with "you are logged in" or "nop, wrong pw/user".
If i have SSL enabled on my page, will my .exe send the information in plain-text? and, will my API answer with plain-text?
Should i do this with POST or GET? i read that POST is better because it sends the information on the Body instead of the URL, but will the answer from the API be protected by the certificate in this case?
Thanks in advance.*

@edit2: Editing 1 more time because thanks to @Ladislav Louka (idk the right way to tag someone) i found that i can intercept the packets and check that this by myself.
My last question is:

Do i need to include the certificate on the client to make everything secure? I mean, does the server really need to know if it's my client that is doing Requests? Couldn't this be unsafe because the certificate could be stolen? like the secret key? and then used for another app to do a brute force attack on my page?

Comment: For the question about POST or GET -> use POST as this is what it is intended for.

As SSL uses asymmetric cipher, communication in both ways should be encrypted - client encrypts what it sends and server does the same.
Whether or not the SSL will work as it should depends on your implementation in .exe and on API (where you can for example deny all http requests on secure items) - you can always check the communication with things like fiddler proxy - intercepting your own internet traffic and seeing if it is https or not.

Comment: Thanks for this, i used Wireshark to capture the packets and then i read the information (thanks to you for making me realize that i could do that hahaha). Without adding anything to my .exe it does the request on HTTPS, i mean the packets are not plain text like on http request (i compared both request, to http and to https on the same site). The only plain-text thing i could find was the information about the certificate, something like "Let's Encrypt..." if this is okay, then everything should work as expected. (i will edit the main post 1 more time to update)

Comment: I like to suggest Fiddler because it has the ability to substitute ssl certificate (where it is not pinned) so you can read even encrypted communication coming from your pc

Comment: For edit2 - Since it seems you are using Let's encrypt adding cert pinning seems like too much work for little benefit. However since it is for log-in so using pinning is not necessarily a bad idea either, depends on usage and needed security

Comment: Thanks for this, this helps to find the answer. I will keep this question opened in case anyone has something to share about this. But to be honest with what you said i think i know enough to start doing some research. Thank you.